# Creating a .deb: dpkg-genbuildinfo: .buildinfo is meaningless

Tags: dpkg, source-packages

So I want to create a .deb file too. I am now blocking at this error:

```
dh_installdeb
 dpkg-genbuildinfo
dpkg-genbuildinfo: error: binary build with no binary artifacts found; .buildinfo is meaningless
```

Which I have difficulties finding information for.

Of course, my recipes may be not correct so I'll appreciate any review!

---

I am building a .deb from sources.

In the `debian/` folder I have:

- compat to 10
- copyright
- changelog
- control
- rules

My control file:

```
Source: foo
Maintainer: foo developers
Section: Web Software
Priority: extra
Version: 1.3.1
Standards-Version: 1.3.1
Build-Depends: debhelper (>= 8.0.0)

Package: foo
Architecture: any
Priority: extra
Homepage: http://foo.com
Depends: sbcl (>= 1.3),
         ${shlibs:Depends},
         libwebkit2gtk-4.0-dev (>= 2.24),
         default-dbus-session-bus | dbus-session-bus,
         glib-networking,
         sqlite,
         gsettings-desktop-schemas,
         libfixposix,
         gstreamer,
         gst-plugins-base-1.0,
         xclip,
         ${misc:Depends}
Description: foo
  foo is foo.
```

My rules file:

```
#!/usr/bin/make -f
DH_VERBOSE = 1

%:
    dh $@

NAME=foo
VERSION=1.3.1
DESTDIR=$(CURDIR)/debian/$(NAME)/


build:
    dh_testdir
    dh_testroot
    dh_prep
    make all

# I quickly tried this
# override_dh_auto_build:
    # dh_auto_build -- all
# with no apparent effect
# (I want to call `make all` of my Makefile).

binary:
    dh_testdir
    dh_testroot
    dh_installchangelogs
    dh_prep
    echo $(DESTDIR)
    make install DESTDIR=$(DESTDIR)

    dh_installdeb
    # dh_gencontrol
    # dh_md5sums
    # dh_builddeb  # only for binary packages ?

# override_dh_auto_binary:
    # make install

clean:
    dh_testdir
    dh_testroot
    # make clean DESTDIR=$(DESTDIR)
    # dh_clean
```

(note that I tried to use `override_dh_auto_build` with no apparent success. I want to call `make all` of my Makefile).

---

I run everything with

```
sudo debuild -us -uc
```

I can see the compilation steps, until the error message.

I see my binary under `debian/foo/usr/local/bin`.

There is a directory `debian/foo/DEBIAN/`, but empty.

Note that when I run the binary target only with

```
sudo fakeroot debian/rules binary
```

it finishes alright:

```
for i in 16 32 128 256 512; do \
    mkdir -p "/home/vince/work/foo/debian/foo//usr/local/share/icons/hicolor/${i}x${i}/apps/" ; \
    cp -f assets/foo_${i}x${i}.png "/home/vince/work/foo/debian/foo//usr/local/share/icons/hicolor/${i}x${i}/apps/foo.png" ; \
    done
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/vince/work/foo'
dh_installdeb
# dh_gencontrol
# dh_md5sums
# dh_builddeb  # only binary packages ?
# make install
```

Thanks!

---

Documentation I'm looking at:

- https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/developers-reference/ch06.en.html
- https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-controlfields.html#s-f-package

Answer (score 0):

I realized defining the `build` target with its lot of "dh_" rules is not the way to go.

I rewrote it with

```
override_dh_auto_build:
    $(MAKE) all
```

I also added

```
override_dh_usrlocal:
    echo
```

to avoid a

> desktop is not a directory

error which I don't understand, and my .deb builds fine.

I still have a

> dpkg-genbuildinfo: error: badly formed line in files list file, line 2

at the end though.